# What is the difference between javascript validation and jQuery validation?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

While i was doing validations for my controls created for user inputs, I am able achieve the same validation by using both jscript and also by jQuery. I really want to know what is the difference between doing validation using jQuery and javascript. And also i want to know are there any specific reasons to go for any one like performance issues ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *jquery is javascript library*, think about it.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery **is** JavaScript. It is just a large pile of functions written by other people that you can use.

Pro: The functions are already written.

Con: It's a large (for some value of large) pile.

The same applies to any other generic JS library (YUI, MooTools, PrototypeJS, etc)

Answer (score 1):

There's no real difference except that jQuery saves you a lot of time, especially if you use the jQuery Validation plugin.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a reasonably large **Javascript Library**. If you don't need to use it, then don't, as it will always bloat you a bit. jQuery is powerful, but if you have a V8 and just use it as something to prop your bike up against in between rides, you don't really need it.

Comment: Careful this is a nerd site, I saw V8 and immediately thought of the V8 JavaScript engine, which is probably a bit off mark `;)`

Comment: haha. I did exactly the same thing about 15 minutes ago when I overheard someone else in the office talking about something non-programming related.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "JavaScript" validation or "jQuery" validation -- validation is a *concept*.

jQuery will always be less performant than vanilla JavaScript because it has additional function calls internally, but it may save you time by being easier for you to write.

Regardless, if you're only validating on the client side (with jQuery or JavaScript) that's bad!  You need to validate on the server side too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between a java-script and a jQuery validation. In jQuery you have plugins available for many scenarios.
 
validation is a way by which you can check your values at client side. Means at the browser.
In many of the cases user can disable java-script from their browser. 
So always try to validate at both end. client & server end.

If you are using asp.net then you can get the benefit of custom validation controls of asp.net.
Here is a link for the same 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

According to [wikki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery):- `Query is a multi-browser JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML. It was released in January 2006 at BarCamp NYC by John Resig. It is currently developed by a team of developers led by Dave Methvin. Used by over 55% of the 10,000 most visited websites`